# Removing Unnecessary Characters from Excel Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-function

Below is a listing of some cells with unnecessary text. The text to remove would be /%%, -, and empty spaces.

[Text and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p1G7.png)
| Text   | Result  |
|:--------|:---------|
| DW80R201UB/AA| DW80R201UB   |
| DW80R201UW/AA| RDW80R201UW |
| DWT24PNA12| RDWT24PNA12  |
| DV-2A/XAA| RDV2A   |
| 1DV-MCK/A1| RDVMCK  |
| 1HAFCU1/XAA| RHAFCU1  |
| HAF-CIN/EXP| RHAFCIN  |

For entries with the forward slash, I use =SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)+1),"") since there can be more than one character after the forward slash.

For everything else, I would use =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")," ","").

I'll usually use the first formula, and then filter the column to only get #VALUE results and use the second formula. I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to get all the models with one nested function.

Comment: To make it easier for people to help, can you show a before and after if what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all characters to the left of a forward slash. If there's no forward slash, then take the original value. From there, substitute any dash or space with an empty string.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)-1),A1),"-","")," ","")
```

[image]

Comment: Drop the `IFERROR()` >> `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1&"/")-1),"-","")," ","")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"");"-";"");" ";"");"%";"");";";"")
```

change semikolon to comma

This will remove all the charakters at once.

Your first formula is not working for me.